# React.js: Props not being received by child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to pass a state variable to a child component as a prop, but the child component is not receiving anything. I saw somewhere that state variables do not update instantly, so I have moved my calls to swap the two child components into the setState callback function. Here's some code..

**Parent Component**

```
//function called by app component to unmount from parent
handleLandingUnmount(enteredCode){
    console.log(enteredCode + ' received in index.js');
    //updating state to give enteredCode to be passed to Chatpage component in props
    this.setState({sessionCode: enteredCode}, function(){
        this.onSessionInState();
    });
}

onSessionInState(){
    console.log(this.state.sessionCode);
    this.setState({renderLandingScreen:false});
    this.setState({renderChatScreen:true});
}

render(){
    //if app component has unmounted, check if chat screen is to be rendered and pass the code as a prop
    const toRender = this.state.renderLandingScreen?<App unmount={this.handleLandingUnmount}/>:
                    this.state.renderChatScreen?<Chatpage sessionCode={this.state.enteredCode}/>:<h1>Something else could go here...</h1>;
    return toRender;
}
```

**Chatpage Component**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
}

render(){ 
    return(
    <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>{this.props.sessionCode}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: your'e passing `sessionCode` to `Chatpage` not to `App`

Comment: that's the way it's supposed to be. sorry, the code is probably quite vague! The App component is unmounted, and then the parent component is meant to pass the returned code as a prop into the chatpage component.

Comment: Please update your question, it's not clear which component is which

Comment: @GershonPapi updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're passing this.state.enteredCode when the code is stored in this.state.sessionCode

Answer (score 1):

It should be this.state.sessionCode.  You are passing in this.state.enteredCode

Comment: Thank you! It's been a long day haha